# Compression in c++ using bitwise operators

Tags: c++, compression, bit-manipulation

We have been given an assignment in which we have to compress 4 bytes into 3 bytes. It wants us to have a compression of 25%, by packing chars into 6 bits instead of 8 bits. It should be 25% exact compression, but my program is doing approx 50%. Code Book is my own "ASCII" sort of table, The bitwise operators are used to perform compression. Does anyone have any idea why it is compressing it by 50% rather than 25%? I know namespace std isn't a good practice, but we are asked to use it. Thanks!`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

unsigned char CodeBook[53][2];

unsigned char FindCharacterCode(unsigned char C)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < 53; j++)
   if (CodeBook[j][0] == C)
   return CodeBook[j][1];
   return 0;
}

void MyCodeBook()
{
    CodeBook[0][0] = 'a'; CodeBook[0][1] = 1;
    CodeBook[1][0] = 'b'; CodeBook[1][1] = 2;
    CodeBook[2][0] = 'c'; CodeBook[2][1] = 3;
    CodeBook[3][0] = 'd'; CodeBook[3][1] = 4;
    CodeBook[4][0] = 'e'; CodeBook[4][1] = 5;
    CodeBook[5][0] = 'f'; CodeBook[5][1] = 6;
    CodeBook[6][0] = 'g'; CodeBook[6][1] = 7;
    CodeBook[7][0] = 'h'; CodeBook[7][1] = 8;
    CodeBook[8][0] = 'i'; CodeBook[8][1] = 9;
    CodeBook[9][0] = 'j'; CodeBook[9][1] = 10;
    CodeBook[10][0] = 'k'; CodeBook[10][1] = 11;
    CodeBook[11][0] = 'l'; CodeBook[11][1] = 12;
    CodeBook[12][0] = 'm'; CodeBook[12][1] = 13;
    CodeBook[13][0] = 'n'; CodeBook[13][1] = 14;
    CodeBook[14][0] = 'o'; CodeBook[14][1] = 15;
    CodeBook[15][0] = 'p'; CodeBook[15][1] = 16;
    CodeBook[16][0] = 'q'; CodeBook[16][1] = 17;
    CodeBook[17][0] = 'r'; CodeBook[17][1] = 18;
    CodeBook[18][0] = 's'; CodeBook[18][1] = 19;
    CodeBook[19][0] = 't'; CodeBook[19][1] = 20;
    CodeBook[20][0] = 'u'; CodeBook[20][1] = 21;
    CodeBook[21][0] = 'v'; CodeBook[21][1] = 22;
    CodeBook[2][0] = 'w'; CodeBook[22][1] = 23;
    CodeBook[23][0] = 'x'; CodeBook[23][1] = 24;
    CodeBook[24][0] = 'y'; CodeBook[24][1] = 25;
    CodeBook[25][0] = 'z'; CodeBook[25][1] = 26;
    CodeBook[26][0] = '0'; CodeBook[26][1] = 27;
    CodeBook[27][0] = '1'; CodeBook[27][1] = 28;
    CodeBook[28][0] = '2'; CodeBook[28][1] = 29;
    CodeBook[29][0] = '3'; CodeBook[29][1] = 30;
    CodeBook[30][0] = '4'; CodeBook[30][1] = 31;
    CodeBook[31][0] = '5'; CodeBook[31][1] = 32;
    CodeBook[32][0] = '6'; CodeBook[32][1] = 33;
    CodeBook[33][0] = '7'; CodeBook[33][1] = 34;
    CodeBook[34][0] = '8'; CodeBook[34][1] = 35;
    CodeBook[35][0] = '9'; CodeBook[35][1] = 36;
    CodeBook[36][0] = '!'; CodeBook[36][1] = 37;
    CodeBook[37][0] = '$'; CodeBook[37][1] = 38;
    CodeBook[38][0] = '('; CodeBook[38][1] = 39;
    CodeBook[39][0] = ')'; CodeBook[39][1] = 40;
    CodeBook[40][0] = '#'; CodeBook[40][1] = 41;
    CodeBook[41][0] = '&'; CodeBook[41][1] = 42;
    CodeBook[42][0] = '%'; CodeBook[42][1] = 43;
    CodeBook[43][0] = '-'; CodeBook[43][1] = 44;
    CodeBook[44][0] = '.'; CodeBook[44][1] = 45;
    CodeBook[45][0] = ','; CodeBook[45][1] = 46;
    CodeBook[46][0] = '\''; CodeBook[46][1] = 47;
    CodeBook[47][0] = ';'; CodeBook[47][1] = 48;
    CodeBook[48][0] = ':'; CodeBook[48][1] = 49;
    CodeBook[49][0] = '?'; CodeBook[49][1] = 50;
    CodeBook[50][0] = ' '; CodeBook[50][1] = 51;
    CodeBook[51][0] = ' '; CodeBook[51][1] = 52;
    CodeBook[52][0] = '¶'; CodeBook[52][1] = 53;

}

int main()
{

     MyCodeBook();

     ifstream In;
     ofstream Out;

     In.open("C://Users//osama//Desktop//code.txt");
     Out.open("C://Users//osama//Desktop//compressed.txt");

     unsigned char Data[4] = { 0 },
     Compressed[3] = { 0 }, Code[4] = { 0 };
     int i; 

     while (!In.eof())
     {

         if (In.is_open())
         {
             for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
             {
                 In >> Data[i];
                 Code[i] = FindCharacterCode(Data[i]);
             }
         }
         else
         {
             cout << "Not open!" << endl << endl;
             return -1;
         }

         Compressed[0] = Code[0] << 2;
         Compressed[0] = (Compressed[0] | Code[1] >> 4);

         Compressed[1] = (Code[1] << 4);
         Compressed[1] = (Compressed[1] | Code[2] >> 2);

         Compressed[2] = (Code[2] << 6);
         Compressed[2] = Compressed[2] | Code[3];

         for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
         {
              Out << Compressed[i];
         }

     }

     In.close();
     Out.close();



     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "_does anyone have any idea why is it doing this_" What's it doing that is unexpected? Please explain the issue that you are having in greater detail.

Comment: I mentioned it is compressing 50% approx, we are asked to compress by 25%.....

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For any given input of your compression algorithm you will get a number between 1 and 53 (let's call it 0 and 53).

How many bits do we need to fit a number this large?

1? in one bit we can store between 0 and 1 - too small.

2? in 2 bits we can store between 0 and 3 - too small.

...

5? in 5 bits we can store between 0 and 31 - too small.

6? in 6 bits we can store between 0 and 63 - big enough.

the inputs are chars, or bytes - 8 bits.

6 / 8 * 100 = 75%

Here's your 25% compression.

Now you need to figure out how to encode 4 lots of 6 bits into 3 bytes of 8 bits.

That's where your bitwise operators (and some bit-shifting) will come in.

Comment: I got that 6 bit thing. So you think bit shifting has some issues? With 4 characters, size 4 bytes in the input file it gives compressed file as 3 bytes. But 419 bytes original is converted into 264 bytes, don't know why....bit shifting is the issue you think?

Comment: @OsamaAsifCInfinitum See comments [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f133925a9258d9a5)